# What is the difference between adding a method to a JavaScript constructor directly and adding a method using prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am using John Resig's JavaScript [class definition style](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). Below is an example class.

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  init: function(isDancing){
    this.dancing = isDancing;
  },
  dance: function(){
    return this.dancing;
  }
});
```

An alternative way to define the dance method would be:

```
Person.prototype.dance = function(){
   return this.dancing;
};
```

I like using the first way but someone suggested me that it is inefficient. What is the difference between the two ways?

Comment: if you've found the answer, answer the question yourself (there's a button marked "Answer your own question" or something) and mark it as answer. that way future peeps can benefit. :-)

Comment: @Thomas Shields Already tried that... but don't have enough points to answer my own question. Will have to wait for 8 hrs :)

Comment: ah, okay. forgot about that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the solution myself.

John Resig's extend function automatically creates a constructor from the object passed as an argument. In the first way, the dance method in the object would automatically be assigned to the prototype of the returned object. It means the returned constructor (class) would be in fact using the 2nd style. So it is unnecessary to use the 2nd way.

Thus when using John Resig's code the first way is NOT inefficient.